# what is the effect of cone back pressure on shock wave angle?

Tags: aerodynamics, aerospace

this is a part of anderson's book :

"Note that, for a given cone angle θc and given
M∞, there are two possible oblique shock waves—the strong- and weak-shock
solutions. This is directly analogous to the two-dimensional case discussed in
Chapter 9. The weak solution is almost always observed in practice on real finite
cones; however, it is possible to force the strong-shock solution by independently
increasing the back pressure near the base of the cone."

how cone back pressure increases shock angle ?

note: its about cone not wedge

does it works for wedge also ?